# Pocketspinx, russian language and keywordspotting

Tags: voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

**The goal is:**
Control smart house via predefined text commands. Without any activation word like okay google, it always listening.

**What's done:**
`pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -hmm /path/zero_ru.cd_cont_4000 -dict /path/my_dictionary_out -lm /path/lmbase.lm.DMP`

Where `my_dictionary_out` has using words one by one. And it works, but I think KWS mode might be better. So I've written a text file like:

`включи свет комнате /1e-50/
выключи свет комнате /1e-50/`

and trying to run sphinx without language model (-lm option), but got nothing. It doesn't recognize commands from keywords file.
What's wrong?

Comment: Tutorial http://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm suggests you need to start spotting optimization with a prerecorded audio file, not with a microphone. Once you have the file you can share it as long as the details to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev as I understood, it's just a way to calculate best threshold.